# Live Stream Issue

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins

I am getting the following error on my facebook app with the facebook live stream widget, but only at random times:

> Live Stream Box configuration error
>
> Live Stream Box couldn't be loaded at this time. Please try again later. For more detailed information on the Live Stream Box please visit the Developer Wiki.

Any ideas? It is really strange because it works sometimes and doesn't work other times. I would have thought that if there was really a configuration issue that it would work 0 times?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the  at the bottom of the page, right before the "< body>".
It worked for me.

http://www.codecheetah.com/solution-facebook-live-stream-box-configuration-error/